# Why 0xc(%ebp) becomes dword [ebp+arg_3]?

Tags: radare2

I'm reversing an x86 binary and I have an instruction that using the at&t syntax is

```
movl 0xc(%ebp), %eax
```

while using the intel syntax is

```
mov eax, dword [ebp+arg_3]
```

I'm using radare2, and at the start of the function it prints

```
; arg int arg_0_1      @ ebp+0x1
; arg int arg_3        @ ebp+0xc
```

Why `[ebp+arg_3]` instead of a simple substitution like `[arg_3]`?

Comment: your question has a typo - the '-' should be '+'.

Answer (score 3):

The reference to `ebp` makes explicit which register is being used to access the variable, and also the fact that the reference is relative, not absolute.  A compiler might have produced an instruction using `esp` instead, if no stack frame exists, or any other register if the code were written by hand.

Further, to show only `[arg_3]` implies that the access is equivalent to another memory location such as `[401000h]`, but with a name instead of a number.

Comment: Could you add a generic expression using the syntax used in the OP?

Comment: @giuscri it's simply a convention chosen by authors of a disassembler you're using. They seem to simply equate arg3 to 0xc and not bother with details :) If your question is about "; arg int arg_3        @ ebp+0xc" - then yeah I agree it's a bit illogical but hey, ask them to fix it :)

Comment: hi I am one of the authors, the reason why we made it like this is that many of the arguments/variables manipulating commands requires prior knowledge of that base register you will use, so think of the `[ebp+arg_3]` as if I was trying to say arg_3 is offsetted  with respect to ebp instead of regular + operator